# body-parser substitution app.use(express.json({ limit: "1mb" })); leads to 500 Internal Server error

Tags: json, express, body-parser

I use [body-parser version 1.19.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) in my NodeJS project together with [express version 4.17.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) like this:

```js
import {
  Router
} from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";

const jsonParser = bodyParser.json({
  limit: "1mb",
});

const apiRoutes: Router = Router();

apiRoutes.post(
  "/:id",
  accessFilter,
  localDFilter,
  jsonParser,
  fetchProductData,
);
```

As the `bodyParser.json()` is marked as deprecated, I would like to get rid off it.

So I have done:

```js
const app = express();
app.use(express.json({
  limit: "1mb"
}));
```

Unfortunately I always get a 500 Internal Server Error for some requests that work perfectly with the deprecated bodyParser.json().

So I have added this in my frontend for axios:

```js
const response = yield call(ApiFetcher.request, {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
  },
  url: getLoadOptionsURI(API_OPTIONS_ENDPOINT, uriParams),
  params: {
    ...getQueryParams(),
    mandant,
  },
});
```

What is the problem with my `express.json(..)` approach ?

Comment: *"...for some requests..."* What requests? What distinguishes them from request where it works? Are the requests pushing the limit? Under it? Over it?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder maybe my description regarding this was bad. One and the same request works with bodyParser.json() and does not work with express.json()

Comment: Is that request pushing the limit? Under it? Over it?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it is way under the limit, only a small request

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
  },
```

with:

```
headers: {
    Content-Type: "application/json",
  },
```

`Accept` header is for the client. it specifies the media type the client expects from the server's response. `Content-type` specifies the media type sent in the request from the client to the server.

Also, just to clarify, some of the comments mentioned that the request might be exceeding the `limit`. If that was the case the response would be `413 Payload Too Large`